# Можно ли передать дополнительные параметры в метод Paint?

Tags: c#

```
lb.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(On2_Paint(lb, new PaintEventArgs(lb.CreateGraphics(), lb.Bounds), 5,5));
```

...

```
private void On2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, int x, int y)
{
     //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: `+= (s, e) => Метод(s,e, другие параметры);`

Comment: Сделайте эти дополнительные параметры полями формы.

Comment: С полями формы не хотелось бы.

Comment: Наверное первый вариант подойдет.

Comment: Передать откуда?